# Making a std::string out of a Char* in C++

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion, macos-carbon

OSX 10.8, Carbon

I have a std::string that I want to derive from a Char*

Example:

```
CFStringRef *s;
char *c[128];

CFStringGetCString(*s, *c, 128, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

int size = sizeof(c);
g_uid.assign(c, size);
```

But I am getting an invalid conversion and I dont understand why

`error: invalid conversion from 'char**' to 'long unsigned int'`

`std::string g_uid = "";` is defined as a global

Comment: That's not a `char *`, it's an array of `char *`.

Comment: If you want to create a `std::string` from a `(const) char *`, you can just do e.g. `const char *blah = "foo"; std::string str = blah;`.

Comment: If it's not clear, just change `char *c[128];` to `char c[128];` probably.

Answer (score 2):

You're too generous with the asterisks - you generally don't need a pointer to `CFStringRef`, and your array is actually an array of pointers, which is not what you want.

It should look more like this:

```
CFStringRef s;
char c[128];

if (CFStringGetCString(s, c, 128, kCFStringEncodingUTF8))
{
    g_uid = c;
}
else
{
     // 128 characters wasn't enough.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. I surely dont want 128 pointers.

Answer (score 0):

If `c` where a `char*`, the following would work:

```
g_uid.assign(c, size);
```

The problem is that `c` isn't `char*`, it's an array of 128 `char*`s:

```
char *c[128];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common beginners mistake in C/C++. I remember making this same mistake back in the day. A declaration like
`char *c[128];` isn't giving you an array of 128 characters as you might be led to believe. Its actually giving you an array of 128 pointers to `char`s. You don't want that.

You want to declare an array of 128 chars which looks like:

```
char c[128];
```

Now you might not think that `c` was a `char*` because you don't see any `*`s but any time you declare an array of something, that variable is automatically a pointer of whatever type you specify. It actually points to the address of the very first element of the array.